# How to execute shell scripts on multiple containers at once in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am want to deploy a Laravel application on AWS EKS.

My application uses Laravel Jobs and Queues. We can use the artisan utility which comes with the Laravel to manage the Queue Worker.

```
php artisan queue:work
php artisan queue:restart
```

I will be using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to monitor the queue process.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

To start the queue when the container is deployed, I am using the ENTRYPOINT script in Dockerfile.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##
# Ensure /.composer exists and is writable
#
if [ ! -d /.composer ]; then
    mkdir /.composer
fi

chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer

##
# Run a command or start supervisord
#
if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    # If we passed a command, run it
    exec "$@"
else
    # Otherwise start supervisord
    /usr/bin/supervisord
fi
```

What I am not able to understand is that if I have multiple replicas of my application running, how will I remotely stop and start the queue process on my running containers.

On EC2, I can use AWS SSM to run shell commands on multiple instances at the same time.

Is there something similar available to AWS EKS also?

Or in general, how do you manage the queue process running on multiple containers in AWS EKS?

Comment: You can use `kubectl scale deployment` to change the number of replicas of a deployment, and that will create or destroy pods as needed.  I wouldn't try to have a pod running without a process in it, just delete the pod and create a new one later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you want to execute a command in multiple containers at once, you can do this, for example, with:

```
for pod in $(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' -l app=myapp); do
  kubectl exec "$pod" mycommand
done
```

This executes `mycommand` in the first container of all Pods with the `app=myapp` label. It doesn't matter if your cluster runs on EKS or anywhere else.